# Short story where a guy becomes a bee, teaches bees to shave the barbs off their stingers

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a story about a guy who inadvertently becomes a bee in his hive and teaches them to shave the barbs off their stingers.

I think it was in an anthology somewhen and was pinched by RL Stine for 'Why I'm afraid of bees.'

Comment: does he become a female bee?

Comment: I believe so. I remember him being in a position to make some changes.

Comment: It seems familiar....two grains of sand and they stab their stingers between them?

Comment: That's the one, @DannyMcG!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

["The Council of Drones"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?43972) by William K. Sonnemann

A scientist teaches the protagonist how to transfer his mind into the queen bee of a bee hive. The queen is named Masoul because she is the soul of the hive.

The protagonist teaches the bees have to use grains of sand to shave the barbs off their stingers. Barbless, they can sting multiple times. With barbs each bee will die it they use their stinger.

The story can be [read at the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Amazing_Stories_v10n12_1936-10/page/n42).